# How to cite ISO or British Standards in LaTeX/BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am trying to cite this [British Standard](http://shop.bsigroup.com/ProductDetail/?pid=000000000030046237) in my Thesis, however using the usual `@keys`doesn't really seem to help make it clear, is there a more practical way to do this as it doesn't really fall into any typical category?

```
@article{BSEN6232
,   author  = {British-Standard-Institution}
,   title   = {Part 2: Determination of density and porosity}
,   journal = {Advanced technical ceramics. Monolithic ceramics. Gerneral and textural properties.}
,   year    = {1993}
,   pages   = {1--16}
,   isbn    = {0580217728}
,   publisher   = {BSI}
,   institution = {British-Standard-Institution}
}
```

Comment: Unless you are following a specific style guide for citations (The Chicago Manual of Style does have a category for government documents), I would treat it as a book. The author is the standardization organization; the title is the full title as it appears on the title page; the standard number is either part of the title or gets a custom field like a series number; the location of publication is the headquarters of the standardization organization unless another place is specified on the title page; and the publisher is the standardization organization again.

Comment: @AndrewCashner thank you for your input, so there is no right way to go about it, the best thing is to state it in a way that shows all the detail without breaking the citation style. I am using IEEE as my style for now but I will go ahead and try it. Thank you for you help, I will update later.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I've found a really useful example [here](http://b-p-i.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/cite-iso-standard-bibtex.html?showComment=1383040964617#c6068992346953979068).

Here's the code:

```
@techreport{ISO13586,
type = {Standard},
key = {ISO 13586:2000(E)},
month = mar,
year = {2000},
title = {{Plastics -- Determination of fracture toughness -- Linear elastic fracture mechanics ({LEFM}) approach}},
volume = {2000},
address = {Geneva, CH},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization}
}
```

And it outputs something like this:

ISO  13586:2000(E)  (2000).   Plastics  –  Determination  of  fracture  toughness  – Linear elastic fracture mechanics (LEFM) approach.  Standard, International Organization for Standardization, Geneva, CH.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think putting `ISO-13586:2000(E)` as author is better. example found [here](http://www.comphys.ethz.ch/wittel/BIB/Publi//ASTM-D5528-94a-eng.html)

Comment: What does the volume mean in this case?

Comment: The link posted by @Foad is now dead. The most recent archived version can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180814170847/http://www.comphys.ethz.ch/wittel/BIB/Publi/ASTM-D5528-94a-eng.html), and seems to contain the cited example.

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of investigation I'm using this schema:

```
@techreport{iso_central_secretary_systems_2016,
address = {Geneva, CH},
type = {Standard},
title = {Systems and software engineering -- {Lifecycle} profiles for {Very} {Small} {Entities} ({VSEs}) -- {Part} 1: {Overview}},
shorttitle = {{ISO}/{IEC} {TR} 29110-1:2016},
url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/62711.html},
language = {en},
number = {ISO/IEC TR 29110-1:2016},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization},
author = {{ISO Central Secretary}},
year = {2016}
}
```

You can compare details with the official info: https://www.iso.org/standard/62711.html

I have another [example using RIS format](http://olea.org/diario/2018/10/19/how_to_cite_ISO_standards.html) too.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

This question is old but i am currently facing exactly the same problem. I tried the described solutions but they did not work for me. I am not an expert but i would suggest the following:

```
@book{ISO.7637-1,
    author      = {International Organization for Standardization},
    year        = {2015},
    title       = {Road vehicles - Electrical disturbances from conduction and coupling: Part 1: Definitions and general considerations},
    address     = {Vernier, Geneva, Switzerland},
    edition     = {{ISO 7637-1:2015(E)}},
    publisher   = {International Organization for Standardization},
    url         = {https://www.iso.org/standard/63098.html},
}
```

My output:

[image: Citing ISO with book]

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. Using book was indeed recommended by the first comment in my question. Using other keys may be required based on the style being used so that the end citation fits.

Answer (score 2):

According to Sec. 17.2. (page 29) of the [IEEE Style Guide](https://development.standards.ieee.org/myproject/Public/mytools/draft/styleman.pdf), the bibtex style
`@techreport` seems to be the most versatile fit, maintaining traceability within the text regarding LaTeX citation style and maintaining compatibility to `bibtex` and `biber` backends.

As suggested by Foad, put the *standard number* into the *author* field in `{...}` to maintain capitals and to prevent abbreviation. I format the number according to the template `{Organisation Number-Part:Year}`, for example:

> {ISO/IEC 42010-3:2000}

This one is applicable for a range of standards, though, not all. (I have been using `@misc` in the past but have changed. Unfortunately, `biber`'s `@standard` style is incompatible with `bibtex` and the latter is required for some journals.)

For alternative formatings, see [here](http://instr.iastate.libguides.com/c.php?g=49430&p=318487).

Answer (score 2):

For British Standards, I found guides for referencing with [Harvard](https://library-guides.ucl.ac.uk/harvard/british-standards) or [APA](https://web.archive.org/web/20161030090228/https://libguides.ioe.ac.uk/c.php?g=482478&p=3299604) styles, but these might only apply for British theses.

Nevertheless, according to the guides the `@book` category is the most suitable:

```
@Book{BSEN2011,
  author    = {British Standard Institution},
  title     = {BS EN 197--1:2011: Cement. Composition, specifications and conformity criteria for common cements},
  year      = {2011},
  publisher = {BSI Standards Limited},
  address   = {London},
  url       = {https://bsol-bsigroup-com.proxy.lib.strath.ac.uk/PdfViewer/Viewer?pid=000000000030391002},
  note      = "Accessed: 30/03/2021"
}
```